# Live server in vscode in Ubuntu is not loading in Android mobile phone

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, localhost

I created a simple webpage and started the `liveserver` in `vscode` in `ubuntu`

- It opened the webpage in Ubuntu with the url http://127.0.0.1:5500/
- I opened the webpage in `android` with the url http://192.168.43.208:5500/
  (I know to open with the router IP and the laptop and `android` are in same network), but it kept on loading and the webpage was not loaded.
- Whereas the same process in it `windows` worked.

Please help me to fix this, I am dual booting `ubuntu` and `windows`.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, the problem is the firewall.
You can set the wi-fi you are connected to to be a private network, then it will work.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-a-wi-fi-network-public-or-private-in-windows-10-0460117d-8d3e-a7ac-f003-7a0da607448d